# Should [table reloaddata] be only called from the main thread?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Just curious.

I suppose the code will force the table to check the number of section and the number of rows in each section and reload all table.

Well guess what, the delegates are stil not called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If it's in AppKit or UIKit, then you must message from the main thread unless an exception to this is documented.